# How to grab a pki certificate with Jersey / Spring?

Tags: java, spring, jersey, x509certificate, pki

I would like to grab a pki certificate when a request happens in jersey / spring.  I tried doing:

```
 @GET
 @Path("/testCert")
 @Produces("text/plain")
 public String testCert(@Context HttpServletRequest request)
 {
   X509Certificate[] certs = (X509Certificate[]) request
       .getAttribute("javax.servlet.request.X509Certificate");
   return "Running... \n";
 }
```

But that didn't grab my cert out of the browser, and I don't know what else to try.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The browser won't send the client certificate unless requested by the server, and you typically need to modify the default server configuration to request a client certificate. For instance, in Tomcat you need to add the attribute `clientAuth=true` to the Connector element that defines your HTTPS listener. You can also use `clientAuth=want`* to request a client certificate, but still allow an unauthenticated connection.

If you have your server set up to request a client certificate and it's still not being sent, then you might need to set up the browser and/or server to trust the other's certificate. This is especially relevant if you're using self-signed certificates -- that definitely won't work without importing the client certificate into the browser trust store.

The [Tomcat SSL How-to](http://tomcat.apache.org/tomcat-6.0-doc/ssl-howto.html) is a good starting point for additional information, some of which is not specific to Tomcat; if you're using a different server you'll obviously need to hunt down its documentation for configuration options.

If all else fails, you can pass `-Djavax.net.debug=ssl` on the command line to get some insight into what's going on at the SSL layer.

* *Older Tomcat versions used `optional` to invoke this behavior. Consult the documentation for your specific Tomcat version to determine the correct property.*

Comment: I'm running my tomcat server out of eclipse, how can I add the attribute there?

Comment: Using Eclipse 3.6 with WTP, I don't see an option to set it through the UI so you have to manually modify the server.xml file. That can be done by expanding the folder icon for your server under the "Servers" project in the Package Explorer.